# User input for timer countdown

Tags: c#, winforms, user-input

I would like to make my timer count down based on user  input.

This is what my form looks like:

[image: this is my timercountdown]

and this is my code:

```
private int counter=80;
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Maximum = counter * 1000;
    progressBar1.Step = 1000;
    timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Start();
    textBox1.Text = counter.ToString();
}


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter--;
    progressBar1.PerformStep();
    if (counter == 0)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
    }
    textBox1.Text = dt.AddSeconds(counter).ToString("mm:ss");
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Enabled = false;
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    textBox1.Clear();
    progressBar1.Value = 0;
}
```

How can I update the timer if the user enters a new value in the textbox?

Answer (score 2):

Attach an OnTextChanged eventhandler to your textbox1. Stop the timer when textinput changes

```
protect void textinput1_OnTextChange(object sender, EventArg e) {
   button2_Click(sender, e);

}
```

Or you can disable user input when timer starts and re-enable it once timer stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set textbox enabled value to false at start button clicked. And enable it again at stop of timer or checked on cancel button. Here is a code:
`textBox1.Enabled = false;`
And
`textBox1.Enabled = true;`